# Find volume of a solid figure that lies between: $x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 4$, $2x^2+2y^2-2z^2\geq 1$, $2z^2\geq x^2+y^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, volume

[image]Find volume of a solid figure that lies between:
$x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 4$,

$2x^2+2y^2-2z^2\geq 1$,

$2z^2\geq x^2+y^2$

I just really can't figure out the limits of integration... any hint would be great

-----edit----

Spherical coordinates:

$x=\rho \sin\varphi \cos\theta$

$y=\rho \sin\varphi \sin\theta$

$z = \rho \cos\varphi$

From sphere: $\rho ^2 \leq 4$ or $\rho \leq 2$.

From hyperboloid: $ 2\rho ^2( \sin^2\varphi - \cos^2 \varphi)\geq 1$

From cone: $\rho ^2(2 \cos^2\varphi - \sin^2 \varphi)\geq 0$

Intersection of sphere and hyperboloid, I got the ellipse:

$\frac{x^2}{\frac{9}{4}}+\frac{y^2}{\frac{9}{4}}=1$ or in spherical coordinates: $\rho^2 \sin^2\varphi=\frac{9}{4}$

Comment: Hint:  This is a volume of a solid of revolution.  Replace $x^2 + y^2$ with $r^2$

Comment: You have a choice of cylindrical or spherical coordinates, I suggest spherical, that gives $\rho \leq 2.$  Alright, the way I learned them, polar coordinates in the plane use angle $\theta,$   then the angle defining "latitude"  was letter $\phi, $ angle away from positive  $z$ axis. Then $\tan \phi \leq \sqrt 2  \; \; $

Comment: Based on the previous comment, pls update the question with your progress if you get stuck. Cylindrical coordinates will require you to split it into two integrals whereas in spherical coordinates, you can write it as one.

Comment: @MathLover I really couldn't do it; I understand that $ρ\leq 2$, and I would say that $θ$ is between $0$ and $2\pi$ since we are taking a full circle in $xy$ plane; i am not sure about this part $tanϕ\leq \sqrt{2}$; also I have added the picture(i considered the z>0 for simplicity)

Comment: Ok I can help. To start with, can you write the equation of all three surfaces in spherical coordinates and can you find the intersection of sphere and hyperboloid?

Comment: @MathLover I have edited the post :)

Comment: When you are typing $sin$ or other trigonometric functions in mathjax, type as $ \text {\sin}$. It appears as $\sin \varphi$ vs. $sin \varphi$.

Comment: I'll note that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider the region above $z = 0$. Due to symmetry the volume bound is same above and below $z = 0$.

The region is defined by,

a) $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq 4$

In spherical coordinates, $\rho \leq 2$ (the sphere)

b) $2x^2+2y^2-2z^2\geq 1$

In spherical coordinates, $ - 2 \rho^2 \cos 2\phi\geq 1$

c) $2 z^2 \geq x^2 + y^2$

In spherical coordinates, $ \tan \phi \leq \sqrt2$

At intersection of hyperboloid and sphere,

$-8 \cos2\phi = 1$ (plugging in $\rho = 2$ in $(b)$)

So, $\cos 2\phi = - \frac{1}{8}$

Notice that this is the region which is outside the hyperboloid and inside the cone and the sphere.

So, $ \sqrt{- (\sec 2\phi) / 2} \leq \rho \leq 2$ (please note for the given limits of $\phi$, $\sec 2\phi$ is negative and so the value inside the square root is positive).

$\arccos \left(\frac{\sqrt7}{4}\right) \leq \phi \leq \arccos \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt3}\right)$ (the lower bound is same as $\cos 2 \phi \leq - 1/8$ and the upper bound is same as $\tan \phi \leq \sqrt2$. I have just rewritten them differently).

$0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I understand it finally! Thank you!

Comment: you are welcome!